# $\frac{M(x,y)}{N(x,y)}$ is homogeneous of degree zero

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, homogeneous-equation

According to the first theorem on Homogeneous Functions, "If $M(x,y)$ and $N(x,y)$ are both homogeneous and of the same degree, then function $\frac{M(x,y)}{N(x,y)}$ is homogeneous of degree zero."

Is it applicable to use $f((\lambda)(x), (\lambda)(y)) = (\lambda)^k(f(x,y))$ to prove that $\frac{M(x,y)}{N(x,y)}$ is homogeneous of degree zero?

Any help is highly appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: You're on the right track. Suppose $M$ and $N$ are homogeneous of degree $n$ and define $$f(x,y) = \frac{M(x,y)}{N(x,y)}.$$ Then $$f(\lambda x, \lambda y) = \frac{M(\lambda x, \lambda y)}{N(\lambda x, \lambda y)} = \frac{\lambda^n M(x, y)}{\lambda^n N(x,y)} = \frac{M(x,y)}{N(x,y)}.$$ Therefore $f(\lambda x, \lambda y) = f(x,y)$ which says that $f$ is homogeneous of degree $0$.

Comment: @Cameron Williams. Thank You for the explanation.

Comment: You're welcome! You were almost there anyway so it's basically your idea anyway ;)